# How to run a scheduled functions when akka actor system terminates

Tags: scala, akka, apache-flink

I have an actor system that I use to schedule the execution of a function that produce an event in a Kafka topic from the flink's map operator. In case of exceptions the actor system is terminated and a stated in the akka documentation (see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scheduler.html#from-akka-actor-actorsystem) all the scheduled tasks should be executed. In my case when the function is executed a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError relating to a class used inside the function is thrown.

```scala
new RichMapFunction[String, String] {
      implicit lazy val executor: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.directExecutor())
      var myActorSystem: ActorSystem = _
      var kafkaProducer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = _
      var runtimeContext: RuntimeContext = _

      override def map(value: String): String = {
        value match {
          case "stop" =>
            throw new Exception("Stop command received")
          case _ =>
            myActorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(FiniteDuration(5L, MINUTES)){
              kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test", value.reverse))
            }
        }

        s"scheduled function on event $value"
      }

      override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
        myActorSystem = ActorSystem("testSystem")
        kafkaProducer = {
          val props = new Properties()
          props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
          // props.put("acks", "all")
          props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
          props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
          new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
        }
        runtimeContext = getRuntimeContext
      }

      override def close(): Unit = {
        println("Terminate actor system...")
        myActorSystem.terminate()
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered simply using Flink's `KafkaProducer` for this task?

Comment: No I did not. But I would like to try timers in `KeyedProcessFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

Actor system termination is asyncroneous and so I used code below.

```scala
Await.result(myActorSystem.terminate(), scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)
```